# Updating an array object without cloning it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pointers

I'm trying to pass a pointer to a function through the parameters, so the function can update the parameters of the object. The object is bound to the view using `{{tasks}}` in the `tasks.component.html` file. Somehow, it looks like the mutations that I do in the `provideAndDisplayTasks()` function don't change the `tasks` property in `tasks.component.ts` at all. I've got similar code that does the same. There it correctly updates the object. I don't understand why it doesn't work in this situation.

How do I update the array, without cloning it?

tasks.component.ts:

```
private provideAndDisplayTasks() {
  const self = this;
  self.tasks.push(new Task());
  console.log('self.tasks', self.tasks);
  this.tasksRepository.provideTasks(self.tasks);
}
```

tasks-repository.ts:

```
public provideTasks(tasks: Task[]) {
  console.log('parameter', tasks);
  this.get('truelime.task/all').subscribe(
    data => this.addTasksToTaskArray(tasks, data),
    error => {
      if (error.status === 401) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
      }
      Logger.getInstance().logError(error);
    }
  );
}

private addTasksToTaskArray(tasks: Task[], tasksDto) {
  const taskArray = tasksDto.truelime_tasks[0].TrueLime_Task;
  for (let i = 0; i < taskArray.length; i++) {
    const taskDto = taskArray[i];
    const task = new Task();
    task.id = taskDto.TaskID;
    task.title = taskDto.TaskTitle;
    task.description = taskDto.TaskDescription;
    task.status = taskDto.TaskStatus;
    tasks.push(task);
    console.log('tasks', tasks);
  }
}
```

Console logs:

[image: console logs]

Comment: the problem is the component view wont react to the tasks array update process, you will need to trigger the change detection by hand if you want to do that

Comment: That's interesting, I have the same setup in a different component and there it does update the view.

Comment: try to use another change detection strategy to see if the value in the view is updated

Comment: I've added a callback which does ``this.tasks = this tasks.slice();``. That updates the view correctly, but the downside to it is that I lose the original pointer.

Comment: Try injecting `cd: ChangeDetectorRef` and calling `this.cd.detectChanges()` 
 in your callback instead of cloning the tasks array